# FFMPEG How to use FIFO to solve a "buffer queue overflow, dropping" error?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I got this code to append an intro and an outro to a video, along with an overlayed logo but I'm getting the error “buffer queue overflow, dropping” on Concat, I've been searching around and it's apparently caused by a matter of filters not requesting the frames fast enough and the recommended solution is to add `FIFO` to the script, could you please explain to me why this happens and how can I use `FIFO` to solve this? I'd like to learn more about FFMPEG but the guides I've stumbled upon are quite basic and don't get into droppings.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%I" -i logo.png -i out1.ts -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1,scale=hd720,setsar=1[vl];[2:v][2:a][vl][0:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 20 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -ar 48000 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Completed\%%~nI.mp4"

pause
```

Comment: This is a regression. For now, use an older binary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try going back, is there much difference in them? Like if I go back to a year older binary, would it impact that much? I know some things changed like '-vcodec' to '-c:v' but not much otherwise

Comment: Use a binary barely older than Dec 18 2016, if you can. `-vcodec` is an alias and still works, as should `-c:v`

Comment: Why don't you report this bug to ffmpeg bug tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to a 2016 FFMPEG build and it works fine again.